# remove parenthesis from a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, nested-lists

I have a list of lists like this:

```
[[('good weather', 0.6307), ('bad weather', 0.431), ('sunny', 0.4036), ('windy', 0.3692), ('rainy', 0.3663)], [('stay home', 0.5393), ('go outside', 0.5009), ('close windows', 0.4794)]]
```

I want to remove the parenthesis and the score for every `sublist`

**Expected outcome:**

```
[['good weather','bad weather', 'sunny', 'windy', 'rainy'], ['stay home', 'go outside','close windows']]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're not "removing parentheses"; you want to convert a list of tuples to a flat list.

Comment: `[[weather for weather, _ in a] for a in your_list]`

Comment: additionally to the last comment, your keep the first element of the vector so you flat the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do list compression here.

```
In [1]: [[s for s, f in a] for a in l]
Out[1]: 
[['good weather', 'bad weather', 'sunny', 'windy', 'rainy'],
 ['stay home', 'go outside', 'close windows']]
```

- `for a in l` looping through the main list
- `[s for s, f in a]` looping through the sublist and fetching the first element using list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to replace `('good weather', 0.6307)` by its first element:

```
a = [[('good weather', 0.6307), ('bad weather', 0.431), ('sunny', 0.4036), ('windy', 0.3692), ('rainy', 0.3663)], [('stay home', 0.5393), ('go outside', 0.5009), ('close windows', 0.4794)]]
b = []

for i in a:
    list = []
    for j in i:
        list.append(j[0])
    b.append(list)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resultant_list = [[value[0] for value in test_list]for test_list in test_lists]
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with an explanation - and a comparison to unpacking by tuple assignment and ignoring all but the first value.